# i am getting "cannot read property _doc of null" i am trying to fetch the id of a user currently logged in and pass to the creator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

below is my schema:

```
module.exports =  buildSchema(`

type Booking {
  _id: ID!
  event: Event!
  user: User!
  createdAt: String!
  updatedAt: String!
}

type Event {
  _id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  price: Float!
  date: String!
  creator: User!
}

type User {
  _id: ID!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  createdEvents: [Event!]
}

type authData {
  userId:ID!
  token:String!
  tokenExpiriation: Int!
}


input EventInput {
    title: String,
     description: String!,
     date: String,
     price:Float!
}

input UserInput {
    email: String!
    password: String!
}

type RootQuery {
    events: [Event!]!
    bookings: [Booking!]!
    login(email:String!, password:String!): authData!
}

type RootMutation {
    createEvent(eventInput:EventInput): Event
    createUser(userInput:UserInput): User
    bookEvent(eventId: ID!): Booking!
    cancelBooking(bookingId: ID!): Event!
}

schema {
    query: RootQuery
    mutation: RootMutation

}
`)

Events.js

    module.exports = {
      events: async () => {
        try {
          const events = await Event.find();
          return events.map((event) => {
            return eventsTemplate(event);
          });
        } catch (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      },
      createEvent: async (args) => {
        const event = new Event({
          title: args.eventInput.title,
          description: args.eventInput.description,
          price: +args.eventInput.price,
          date: new Date(args.eventInput.date),
          creator:req.userId,
        });
        let createdEvent;
        try {
          const result = await event.save();
          createdEvent = eventsTemplate(result);
          const creator = await User.findById(req.userId);

          if (!creator) {
            throw new Error("User not found.");
          }
          creator.createdEvents.push(event);
          await creator.save();

          return createdEvent;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        }
      },
    };
```

my eventsTemplate is below

```
const eventsTemplate = (event) => {
  return {
    ...event._doc,
    _id: event.id,
    date: dateToString(event._doc.date),
    creator: user.bind(this, event.creator),
  };
};
```

Comment: @xadm i think you are correct but the thing is i am quite new to mongo but from my understaing if you save mongo assigns an object id to it that you dont have to implicitley add it is returned as a resultset but from your answer could you please assist me with a little example of what you mean

Comment: entire `result` (object returned from `event.save()`) is `null`

Comment: @xadm sorry but how is that possible because i am getting my result from "req.userId", which is returned from my graphql query could you take a look at it, i am confused now, would you be nice enough to show me small code snippet so i can a picture what you mean

Comment: this `const result = await event.save();` gives `result` equal to `null`. Why? I don't know ;)

Comment: @xadm i see what you mean , i was thinking mongo always has an _id attached to what you save, so how do you suggest i solve this, its been 3days i am trying to work around this i am sorry for too much of your time

Comment: leave `_id` ... error is about `_doc` but it's from bad `save()` `result` ... fix `Event.save()` ?

Comment: @xadm sorry i am lost how do i go about it?, because i am failing to see where event.save is wrong because if you look closely i am creating event const inside creaEvent method and inthe mongo all fields including the the i.d are being saved but why cant i retrieve the same i i.d that i managed to save do you mind i share with you my branch?